# Why end a javascript file with 0 && 0

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Digging into the `@babel/core` package, almost every transpiled .js file ends with the following line:

```
0 && 0
```

What is the purpose of this?

For example, see [transform-ast.js](https://unpkg.com/browse/@babel/core@7.20.12/lib/transform-ast.js), the transpilation of [transform-ast.ts](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/v7.20.12/packages/babel-core/src/transform-ast.ts).

Comment: It's important to note that the _transpiled_ files end with that, not the [original source](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/main/packages/babel-core/src/transform-ast.ts).

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar e.g. https://unpkg.com/browse/@babel/core@7.20.12/lib/transform-ast.js

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar You too have enough reputation to suggest an edit to a question...

Comment: probably related https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/14663

Answer (score 0):

I see the `0 && 0` thing was added from version `7.18.6`. From [babel config comment](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/v7.18.6/babel.config.js#L745):

> Inject `0 && exports.foo = 0` hints for the specified exports,
> to help the Node.js CJS-ESM interop. This is only
> needed when compiling ESM re-exports to CJS in `lazy` mode.

So, this states that it was added to help understand the Node.js CommonJS modules that is compilable when ECMAScript modules are re-exported to CommonJS module in `lazy` mode.

Comment: It would be pretty wild to just add to add this as an end-of-file marker without any purpose. Plausible, but unlikely and your answer sounds mostly like conjecture. If you have _any_ evidence, share.

Comment: Sure this probably doesn't affect me, but I'm curious nonetheless which is why I asked.

Comment: Thanks for doing some research and finding out *what* does this. The comment you shared says *something* but it's still pretty unclear. I'm looking for *why* not *how*, but it's interesting. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: It's not `0 && exports.foo = 0` though, it's `0 && 0`.

Comment: @AKX That's just a hint.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that this doesn't explain why `0 && 0` would appear at the end of the files.

Comment: `export.foo = 0` is transpiled to `0`.

Comment: Check the code: `path.pushContainer("body", template.statement.ast`0 && (${assign})`);` where `assign` results in `0`.

Comment: Right. IOW, you could argue there's a bug in that code; no statement should be emitted if `seen` is empty.